# Help with Many-to-Many Filtering Queries

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, query-optimization

I'm trying to figure out how to efficient implement tags in my database.

One approach is to have a table of articles (let's say `Articles, ArtID int PK, ArtText varchar(max)`), and a table of tags (let's say `Tags, TagID int PK, TagTitle varchar(15)`). And then I'll create a join table to create a many-to-many relationship between Articles and Tags (let's say `ArticleTags, ArtID int, TagID int (compound primary key)`.

My first question is what is the best way to write a query to find all the articles associated with a given tag? I know about joins if I want to return the combined data, but what is the most efficient query if I just want to know which article rows are associated with a particular tag. In real life, I will need to find articles with multiple tags and it would be nice to also find articles that are NOT associated with a particular tag.

My second question is about whether or not my Tags table should have an int PK? Does it make more sense to use the TagTitle as the primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1a) My first question is what is the best way to write a query to find all the articles associated with a given tag?

```
select ArtID  -- if only IDs are required
from ArticleTags
where TagID=1  -- or use the text (where tagtitle='x')

select A.*
from ArticleTags T inner join Articles A on A.ArtID = T.ArtID
where T.TagID=1
```

1b) In real life, I will need to find articles with multiple tags

```
-- has tags 1,3 and 8
select T1.ArtID
from ArticleTags T1
inner join ArticleTags T2 on T1.ArtID = T2.ArtID and T2.TagID = 3
inner join ArticleTags T3 on T1.ArtID = T3.ArtID and T3.TagID = 8
where T1.TagID=1
  -- or use the text (tagtitle='x') on each filter
```

In some cases, this form works faster. This or the preceeding one can be joined to get the article records.

```
select ArtID
from (
    select T1.ArtID from ArticleTags T1 where T1.TagID=1
    union all
    select T2.ArtID from ArticleTags T2 where T2.TagID=3
    union all
    select T3.ArtID from ArticleTags T3 where T3.TagID=8
) X
group by ArtID
having count(ArtID) = 3
```

1c) and it would be nice to also find articles that are NOT associated with a particular tag.

```
select A.*
from Articles A
left join ArticleTags T on T.ArtID = A.ArtID and T.TagTitle = 'nomatch'
where T.ArtID is null
```

2) My second question is about whether or not my Tags table should have an int PK? Does it make more sense to use the TagTitle as the primary key?

I am firmly in the camp that says each table should have a sequential, meaningless integer ID.  It reduces space of storage (FK from other tables) and int lookup / range merging is always faster than varchar.

Comment: For 1c I'd use `NOT EXISTS` http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/ Why are you using `UNION ALL` in 1b as well? This seems much more straight forward with `IN(1,3,8)`

Comment: It's a bit of a muchness. Depending on data distribution, it is not always the case that one that will be faster than the other. Although NOT EXISTS is possibly easier to read concisely

Comment: Can someone help me understand why it wouldn't be faster to do something like `SELECT a.ArtID, ... FROM Articles a INNER JOIN ArticleTags at ON a.ArtID = at.ArtID INNER JOIN Tags t ON at.TagID = t.TagID WHERE t.TagTitle = 'tag'`?

Comment: Caveat for (1)(a) -- this only works properly if there is a unique constraint on combinations of `TagID` and `ArtID` in the `ArticleTags` table. Seems reasonable that there would be, but if not, multiple identical tags would return `Article.*` multiple times. Using `EXISTS` avoid this, is more expressive of the desired output, and the execution plan is just as efficient (should be nearly identical).

Comment: @richardtallent: I think it is implied in this answer that uniqueness is guaranteed in some way, because e.g. 1b#2 would produce clearly wrong results, not merely duplicates, if it hit duplicate pairs of TagID and ArtID. And I agree, it is only reasonable to have a unique index on those two columns.

Comment: @ric - the question states `ArtID int, TagID int (compound primary key)` == unique, from my reading

Comment: @cyberkiwi: Good reading! Can't speak for richardtallent, but I did miss that detail for sure. Oh, well. At least I can see now that my vision of what's reasonable has not been too far from common sense. :)

Comment: @cyberkiwi, I did indeed miss that constraint. I still think EXISTS() is a more clear construct and will result in the same if not an ever-so-slightly better execution plan, but joins are a perfectly valid solution.

Answer (score 2):

(1)

(a) Articles with a particular tag:

```
SELECT columns FROM Articles WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT null FROM ArticleTags at 
    WHERE at.ArtID = Articles.ArtID AND at.TagID=x)
```

(b) Articles without a particular tag:

```
SELECT columns FROM Articles WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT null FROM ArticleTags at 
    WHERE at.ArtID = Articles.ArtID AND at.TagID=x)
```

(2) Using TagTitle is faster if you're just getting the list of tags associated with an article, but for most other possible operations, a surrogate `int` will be faster.

Comment: Thanks, but is this really the most efficient way? For each and every row in the Articles table, this approach would have to scan the ArticleTags table.

Comment: Try yourself and look at the execution plan for the query. As long as you have indexes for ArticleTags.TagID and ArticleTags.ArtID, SQL Server's actual plan will be extremely efficient. If read efficiency is much more important than write, be sure to put these fields in the clustered index.